# Need to install imagemagick on linux shared hosting

Tags: linux, imagemagick, godaddy-api

I'm using a godaddy server and need to install imagemagick on a shared linux server which doesn't have admin rights. I've had multiple people check my code and nothing is wrong with it, the problem is godaddy's implementation of imagemagick isn't working. Running PHP 7.4.

Expected imagemagick to work since it is enabled in select php version, but images called with it aren't loading and producing http error 500 on code page.

```html
<?php
 
namespace Controller\Main;
use Resource\Core\AppController;
use Resource\Core\Registry;
 
class AdoptimageController extends AppController{
 
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();   
    }
 
    public function index(){
        $mysidia = Registry::get("mysidia");
    }
 
    public function view($aid){
        $mysidia = Registry::get("mysidia");
 
        //A not-so-clean way to get the id of the parent page
        $fullurl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $scrub = explode('/',trim($fullurl,'/'));
        $cleanaid  = end($scrub);
 
        $adopt = $mysidia->db->select("owned_adoptables", array(), "aid='$cleanaid'")->fetchObject();
 
        if($adopt->species == "floof"){
 
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 0){
                $images = array('http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\colours\\' . $adopt->body . '_colour2.png', #0
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\colours\\' . $adopt->body . '_colour1.png', #1
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\markings\\' . $adopt->body . '\\' . $adopt->marking_1 . '.png', #2
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\lines\\' . $adopt->body . 'fluddy_body_lineart.png'); #3
            }
            elseif($adopt->currentlevel == 1){
                $images = array('http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\colours\\' . $adopt->body . 'fluffy_body__colour2.png', #0
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\colours\\' . $adopt->body . 'fluffy_body_colour1.png', #1
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\markings\\' . $adopt->body . '\\' . $adopt->marking_1 . '.png', #2
                'http:\\\\emotidogs.online\\picuploads\\dog_images\\adult\\lines\\' . $adopt->body . 'fluffy_body_lineart.png'); #3
            }
            elseif($adopt->currentlevel == 2){
                //Snipped for length
            }
            elseif($adopt->currentlevel == 3){
              //Snipped for length
            }
            elseif($adopt->currentlevel == 4){
                //Snipped for length
            }
            elseif($adopt->currentlevel == 5){
                //Snipped for length
            }
        }
 
 
        // This creates the Imagick class that we will use.
        $composed_image = new \Imagick($images);
        $clut = new \Imagick();
        $timestamp = time();
 
        if($adopt->species == "floof"){
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 0){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->fluffy_body_colour2")); // Colours the fluffy body colour 2
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[0]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(1);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->fluffy_body_colour1")); // Colours the fluffy body colour 1
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[1]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(2);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->marking_1_colour")); // Colours fluffy body marking 1
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[2]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->evaluateImage(\Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, $adopt->marking_1_opacity, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
 
            }
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 1){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->fluffy_body_colour2")); // Colours the fluffy body colour 2
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[0]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(1);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->fluffy_body_colour1")); // Colours the fluffy body colour 1
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[1]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(2);
                $clut->newImage(1, 1, new \ImagickPixel("$adopt->marking_1_colour")); // Colours body marking 1
                $composed_image->clutImage($clut);
                $clut->destroy();
                $composed_image->compositeImage( new \Imagick($images[2]), \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0 ); // Keeps within colour
                $composed_image->evaluateImage(\Imagick::EVALUATE_MULTIPLY, $adopt->marking_1_opacity, \Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
            }
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 2){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $composed_image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
               //Snipped for length
            }
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 3){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $composed_image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
               //Snipped for length
 
            }
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 4){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $composed_image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
               //Snipped for length
 
            }
            if($adopt->currentlevel == 5){
                $composed_image->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $composed_image->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');
               //Snipped for length
 
            }
        }
 
        $image = $composed_image->mergeImageLayers(\Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
        $image->setImageFormat('png');
 
 
        if($adopt->lastupdate >= $adopt->imglastupdate && file_exists('C:\\wamp64\\emotidogs\\online\\picuploads\\adopt_images\\' . $adopt->aid . '.png')){
                    unlink('C:\\wamp64\\emotidogs\\online\\picuploads\\adopt_images\\' . $adopt->aid . '.png');
                }
                else{
                    $mysidia->db->update("owned_adoptables", ["lastupdate" => $timestamp, "imglastupdate" => $timestamp], "aid = '{$adopt->aid}'");
                    $storepath = 'C:\\wamp64\\emotidogs\\online\\picuploads\\adopt_images\\' . $adopt->aid . '.png';
                    $image->writeImage($storepath);
                }
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        echo $image;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Godaddy's version is rather old and might be buggy.  Try installing the portable version "magick" at https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Comment: I downloaded it and uploaded to public_html, but how do I run it from there?

Comment: It's a binary with delegates combined. So from terminal, you should just have to put the `path_to/magick input commands output`.  Sorry, never used it myself

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Type `path_to/magick input commands output` in a bash terminal window. Fill in your path to where you installed it. Fill in any commands you need.

Comment: Sorry the install I gave you is not for PHP Imagick. It is for command line only. Your title asked for Imagemagick, not PHP/Imagick.  I do not know how to install PHP and Imagick.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Apparently the php version is installed but it still doesn't work

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Comment: Godaddy doesn't have pecl. Also I don't have access to the php extension folder, it's shared hosting.

Comment: Can't you download and install whichever version you need from http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

Comment: How would I install it if the pecl command doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. I have never installed Imagick.